# How to add an extension door chime when wiring inaccessible

Tags: circuit-design

I have a two wire door bell system comprising a simple bell push (no light) with two wires chased into the walls leading to the bell chime; the two wires continuing to the garage where the transformer is installed. The transformer has 8, 16 and 24V ac output options. The chime takes 8 – 16V ac. and is working.

[image]

I want to connect an extension bell whose twin wires also terminate in the garage beside the transformer and I am tying to think of a way of connecting such that the extension bell is also activated by the same bell push. The problem is I do not have access to run extra wire(s) to the existing bell so a simple in parallel connection across it is not possible nor therefore is a relay in parallel. I tried a 24V ac coil relay in series but it stops the existing bell from working.  I have not specified the extension bell because I can purchase to suit if relevant. This really is not worth destroying the decoration in the hallway where the bell is; I was hoping to wire it in the garage but I’m stumped. Is it possible?

Update:
The transformer outputs are 8, 12 and 24V ac not 8,16,24 as I incorrectly typed before. Voltage measurements are:

Nominal        8      12      24
Open circuit   11.3   16.3    28.5
Bell pushed    9.1    11.6    14

Resistance across bell loop 7 ohm.

The bell has been connected to the 24V outlet When I restored the wiring, I connected to the 12V outlet then to the 8V and the bell works fine. The simple answer seems to be to just stick another similar bell in series and use the 24V outlet.

Comment: I would side-step the wiring and use a current sensor at the transformer to detect the load of ringing the bell. You can monitor the current sensor and trigger any number of outputs, smart home or otherwise, with an MCU.

Answer (score 1):

This requires minimal of components.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to revert to 24V ~ and connect the chimes in series as shown.

[image]

Comment: I came to that conclusion. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Anytime! Looks like your edit and my answer were simultaneous!

Answer (score 0):

The idea of putting something in series with the existing circuit is correct.  The problem is the amount of current the existing bell needs to function.  A 24 V relay coil is too high a resistance to put in series with the existing bell.

The electronic route is to put a small resistor (or two inverse-parallel diodes) in series in the circuit, and have a comparator look at the voltage across it and drive a transistor that drives a relay with a 12 Vac coil, and the contacts switch the existing AC transformer to the new bell.  Low cost parts, small piece of perf board, but you have to have a bit of circuit wiring experience in your tool belt.

Another option that is non-contact is to thread one available wire through a current transformer, and connect the secondary to the comparator as above.  There probably is an industrial control module that has everything in one package, but that will be relatively expensive.

Another option is to measure the existing bell current, and use that to calculate the relay coil characteristics that will let the existing bell function.  Maybe use the 24 V transformer tap and a 6 V relay coil with a resistor in parallel with it.  The resistor lets most of the circuit current bypass the relay coil, so the coil's higher resistance doesn't starve the bell.

Hmm ... I probably should have put that one first.

Leave things connected to the 16 V output.  To start, measure the transformer output voltage when the button is pressed.  Next, disconnect both wires from the transformer, have someone push the button, and measure the resistance of the loop.  That is the resistance of the existing bell.  Update your question with those numbers, and the rest of the circuit can be calculated.